# Why IOS mail app image attachments are inline?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, mail.app

When I attach an image in mail app, the image always attached as inline. Same happened when I use the iCloud mail app via web(Windows). Why these kind of issues aren’t fixed yet. This doesn’t happen in Gmail app. ;(

can anyone help me how to attach an image as an attachment. Not inline.

Thanks

Comment: Apple Mail will show the attachment where you insert it in your Mail compose view. No changing that.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson it’s really annoying. Gmail has way better features than this app. I don’t know why Apple keep it like this.

Comment: I tried to do this on my iPhone, but it seems impossible, which is a real pity... iPhone apps are often very limited in features compared to Android world.